# while changing the language in nuxt3 application, half content gets missed

Tags: typescript, nuxt.js, nuxt3

when changing or refreshing the page in nuxt3 application half of the contents got missed.

This works properly in local server, but issue persists in the aws amplify server preview link

what can be done to resolve the issue